# Error when trying to bind function to button in Python application for anomaly detection on Shapelets platform

Tags: python, function, time-series, visualization, matrix-profile

I'm trying to bind a function to a button in my application so that it triggers an anomaly detection. Here's the code I have so far:

```
button = app.button("Execute anomaly-detection")
app.place(button)

ailtair_chart1 = app.altair_chart(title='MLII', data=df['MLII'])
app.place(line_chart1)

ailtair.bind(computeAndPlotAnomalies, df['MLII'], windowSize, top_k, triggers=[button])

app.register()
```

However, when I click on the button, I get Error: Internal Server Error. Runtime error executing computeAndPlotAnomalies. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour] and [ask]. What is the `system error` that you got? Include it in your question as text.

Comment: I was refering to the error when using the Shapelets dataapp which is. 
Error: Internal Server Error. Runtime error executing computeAndPlotAnomalies

Answer (score 0):

ok in your case scenario, I will assume that when creating the function you returned the right data type.

otherwise  if your data is a line chart you should try to use the line:chart function as this

```
button = app.button("Execute anomaly-detection")

app.place(button)

line_chart1 = app.line_chart(title='MLII', data=df['MLII'])

app.place(line_chart1)

line_chart1.bind(computeAndPlotAnomalies, df['MLII'], windowSize, top_k, triggers=[button])

app.register()
```

if you have any more trouble after this example, you can look at your documentation
https://shapelets.io/doc/
https://github.com/shapelets/shapelets-demo